# How can i set a local Variable in Javascript in a function i used as parameter?

Tags: javascript, cordova, barcode-scanner

I've got a problem in Javascript using Barcodescannerplugin for Phonegap in an Android Application.

The plugin I use is bringing a small Javascript to enable using the Barcodescanner in my Phongap application. But in my opinion the interface of the provided javascript functions isn't that optimal, cause I don't want to do an errorhandling at every position where I use these methods.

That's why I tried to make that interface more easy in the way, that I just have to call a method `scanBarcode()` and the calling script is getting the text from the scanned or nothing, if something fails. Here is the code:

```
function scanBarcode(){
    var resultText = '';
    window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan( 
        function(result) {
            if (!result.cancelled){
                resultText = result.text;
            }
        },
        function(error) {
            alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
        }
    );
    return resultText;
}
```

The plugin I use can be found at: [Github Phonegap Plugins Android/BarcodeScanner](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner/)

The result of my Method is always the same, an empty string.
I think the reason is the variable scope, but I am not sure how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because the `window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan` method executes asynchronously - the success callback is not called until the method has returned.

I'd recommend returning a `Promise` object from your method, so something like (using jQuery as an example):

```
var result = $.Deferred();
window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan( 
    function(result) {
        if (!result.cancelled){
            result.resolve(result.text);
        }
    },
    function(error) {
        result.reject(error);
    }
);

return result;
```

Comment: OK, so isn't there any way to make these interface more easy in the way I tried it?

Comment: Ah ok thank you, I'll try these example cause we are using jQuery Mobile in these Webapplication as well.

Comment: Hi Rich, I've used your examplecode and jQuery Mobile now. The result is that I get an Object back, but i can't get the scanned string out of it. Or Otherwise didn't I understand the API documentation right if i thought, that the parameter given to the resolve method of the deferred object is the value which is returned to all callbackmethods? I tried something like that:  function clickScanBarcode(){
  var result = scanBarcode();
  alert(result);
 }

Comment: @Marcus: No, the value that is returned *is* the deferred object. You have to register callbacks on that object, which get executed when the deferred object gets resolved. http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help, now it works :)

For all other who has got these problem too, the resolution looks like that:

```
function scanBarcode(){
    var resultObject = $.Deferred();
    window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
        function(result) {
            if (!result.cancelled){
                resultObject.resolve(result.text);
            } else {
                resultObject.resolve('');
            }
        },
        function(error) {
            resultObject.resolve('');
        }
    );
    return resultObject;
}
```

And now it is easy to get the scanned value just by saying that:

```
function clickScanBarcode(){
    var result = scanBarcode();
    result.done( function(text){
        alert('Barcodetext:'+text);
    });
}
```

I've changed the code for error and cancelled in the way, that i always get an empty string to handle with. More errorhandling isn't useful in my case.

Greetings,
Marcus